# Find All Partial Matches in Email Prefix

Tags: python, regex

Given a name and an email id, I want to find if any prefix of that name(should start with the first character and can extend till 'n' chars) is in the email

```
Name = "mohan". Possible prefixes : 'm','mo','moh','moha', 'mohan'
1) email = "mohanabc"   : Matched till mohan so match count is 5
2) email = 'abcmohacde' : Again Matched till 'moha', so match count it 4
3) email = 'mohabc'     : Match count is 4
4) email = 'nahom'      : Match count 0
5) email = 'ohan'       : Should return match count 0. Looking for the prefix of that name.
```

I am using python, so any python specific solutions are greatly appreciated. But I am happy to get any other regex based soln as well (well python accepts general regex, so shouldn't be a problem).

One naive solution is to add all the prefixes to the regex and match the email. But I am looking for something specific if any.

Comment: Question is marked 2 down, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
m(?:o(?:h(?:a(?:n)?)?)?)?
```

The number of potential prefixes is the length of the match.

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/24), see the capture groups in the **right pane**.

**Explanation**

- `m` must be matched
- The non-capturing group `(?:o ... )?` is optional
- The non-capturing group `(?:h ... )?` is optional
- The non-capturing group `(?:a ... )?` is optional
- The non-capturing group `(?:n)?` is optional

**In Python:**

We retrieve all the matches and take the longest. Here, the string `abcmohmohaabc` contains both `moh` and `moha`

```
subject = "abcmohmohaabc"
matches = re.findall("m(?:o(?:h(?:a(?:n)?)?)?)?", subject)
print("Matches: ", matches)
longest = sorted(matches)[-1]
print("Longest: ",  longest )
print( len(longest) )
for i in range(1, 1+len(longest)):
    print(longest[:i])
```

**Output**

```
Matches:  ['moh', 'moha']
Longest:  moha
4
m
mo
moh
moha
```

---

### Special Case: Internal Repetition Within Sought String

Please note that if the sought string has internal repetition of the first characters (for instance if instead of searching for `mohan` we were searching for `momohan`, a string such as `momomohan` would cause trouble. In that's a concern, we can wrap the regex in a capture group, and the capture group in a lookahead, allowing for overlapping matches: `(?=(m(?:o(?:m(?:o(?:h(?:a(?:n)?)?)?)?)?)?))`. The code would be identical.

```
subject = "ABmomomohanABmomohCD"
matches = re.findall("(?=(m(?:o(?:m(?:o(?:h(?:a(?:n)?)?)?)?)?)?))", subject)
print("Matches: ", matches)
longest = sorted(matches)[-1]
print("Longest: ",  longest )
print( len(longest) )
for i in range(1, 1+len(longest)):
    print(longest[:i])
```

**Output:**

```
Matches:  ['momo', 'momohan', 'mo', 'momoh', 'mo']
Longest:  momohan
7
m
mo
mom
momo
momoh
momoha
momohan

# NOTE: in the ABmomomohanABmomohCD input string, the five matches are found 
# at the following starting positions:
#   ABmomomohanABmomohCD
#   1:mo
#     2:momohan
#       3:mo
#              4:momoh
#                5:mo
```

**Generating the Regex Dynamically**

Here is one way:

```
name = "mohan"
theregex = "(?=(" + name[0]
for c in name[1:]:
    theregex += "(?:" + c
for c in name[1:]:
    theregex += ")?"
theregex += "))"
print(theregex)
```

Output:

```
(?=(m(?:o(?:h(?:a(?:n)?)?)?)?))
```

Comment: abcmohmohaabc should give moha - 4, but am getting 3.

Comment: You are getting 3 because I am returning the first match, which is `moh`. If you like, I can tweak it to return all matches, then we take the longest.

Comment: Added Python code for the longest match to handle strings like `abcmohmohaabc`

Comment: Thanks zx81, I was generating all the prefixes and doing a "|" join of all of them. This is simpler, I just need to manipulate the characters given

Comment: Yes, I was thinking you would generate the regex dynamically? With this repetitive pattern it should be easy. :)

Comment: Added a section with code at the bottom: Generating the Regex Dynamically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57793/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-zx81).

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of thing I would probably recommend *tries*  (the data structure) over *regexes*, particularly for larger data sets.

There is a *Python* implementation of *tries* which is a wrapper around the *marisa-trie* C++ library.

https://github.com/kmike/marisa-trie

They describe its performance characteristics as follows:

> String data in a MARISA-trie may take up to 50x-100x less memory than
>   in a standard Python dict; the raw lookup speed is comparable; trie
>   also provides fast advanced methods like prefix search.

It lets you do things like this:

> Find all items from this trie that starts with a given prefix:

```
>> trie.items(u'fo')
[(u'foo', (1, 2)), (u'foo', (2, 1), (u'foobar', (3, 3))]
```

Comment: Thanks @ken This seems to be cleaner solution. But this is a small part of our project, am not sure if I can add the trie just for this. Anyways, knowing marisa-trie is good. Thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem. Worth keeping in mind if your data footprint increases. =)